# Set decimal places for 4 for results from Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, decimal

Following is the Code that i have built to calculate the failure rate of specific product.

`ASU QTY` - Is the total products which are in Warranty

`Dispatch QTY` - Is the Total Failure that the product has

`Fiscal_Week` - Is the Week that the product Failed

If i need to get the `Failure Rate` - Which is denoted as `MDR`

I need to Divide Dispatch `QTY/ ASU QTY`

In the Code i have used the following

`cast(isnull([Dispatch QTY],0) as float)/Cast(isnull([ASU QTY],0) as float) * 100  as 'MDR'`

I need the following Out of the output

1. Set Decimal Places to 5 Only
2. Add %

Full Code to pull Failure Rate

```
select a.FISCAL_WEEK
    ,isnull([ASU QTY],0) as 'ASU QTY'
    ,isnull([Dispatch QTY],0) as 'Dispatch QTY' 
    ,cast(isnull([Dispatch QTY],0) as float)/Cast(isnull([ASU QTY],0) as float) * 100  as 'MDR'



    from ASU a left Join dispatch b
    on
    a.FISCAL_WEEK = b.FISCAL_WEEK

    order by a.FISCAL_WEEK`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CAST` the result to `decimal(20,5)` and then to `string`

```
cast (
     cast (
           cast(isnull([Dispatch QTY],0) as float)
         / cast(isnull([ASU QTY],0) as float) * 100 
          as decimal(20,5) )
     as varchar(20) ) + '%'  as 'MDR'
```